# Has the ability to locally redefine an identifier inside of a block always existed in C?

Tags: c, scope, uniqueidentifier, identifier

I am working through **"The Standard C Library" by P.J. Plauger** which was written based on the ANSI C Standard.  I am having some trouble with the following problem in the book:

> > "Write a (correct) program that contains the line:

```
    x:  ((struct x *)x)->x = x(5);
```

Now, I know that I would never *want* to have a line of code like that in my code, but for the sake of learning something new I decided to try it out.  I have written the following code in an attempt to make it work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

struct x
{
    uint16_t x;
};

uint16_t x (uint16_t number)
{
    return number;
}

int main (void)
{
    intptr_t x;
    struct x my_struct;

    x = (intptr_t)&my_struct;

    x: ((struct x *)x)->x = x(5);

    if (my_struct.x == 6)
    {
        goto x;
    }

    printf("my_struct.x: %d", my_struct.x);

    return 0;
}
```

However, I get the following error when compiled with *mingw32-gcc -Wall -g*:

**error: called object 'x' is not a function**

If I change the function `uint16_t x (uint16_t number)` to `uint16_t y (uint16_t number)` and call it as such, then the compiler is happy and my program runs properly.  Based on the above, it looks to me like I am redefining the function `x()` locally as `intptr_t x`.

Is there a point that I am just missing or was this a construct that was allowed in ANSI C but not in later standards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
#define x(n) n
```

instead of:

```
uint16_t x (uint16_t number)
{
    return number;
}
```

and you program will be valid.

If you look at C Standard (e.g., 6.2.3p1 in C99), there are 4 different name spaces, for: labels, structure / union members, tags and ordinary identifiers. Your function identifier and the object identifier were living in the same name space.

Comment: Ahhh... totally missed that.  Brilliant, thanks @ouah.

Answer (score 1):

The local variable name will hide the global function name. This is standard behavior and not something new.

The author of the book is looking for a solution that circumvents this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a system specific, hacky program in which the expression appears, without any preprocessor macro being used. The function called by `x(5)` multiplies its argument by `5`, and we see that the resulting `25` ends up in the `x` structure member:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct x {
  char array[1024];
  int x;
};

int func(int arg)
{
  return 5 * arg;
}

void after(void)
{
}

int foo(int (*x)(int))
{
  x: ((struct x *)x)->x = x(5);
}

int main(void)
{
  struct x *xs = mmap(0, 4096, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC,
                      MAP_ANON | MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);
  memcpy(xs, (void *) func, (char *) after - (char *) func);
  foo((int (*)(int)) xs);
  printf("xs->x = %d\n", xs->x);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
 xs->x = 25
```

The trick is that we copy the function into the structure, so that the address of the structure is a pointer to the machine code; a de facto pointer to a function. For this to work in the given environment (Ubuntu GNU/Linux), we need to allocate some memory and make it executable.

The program isn't "incorrect"; it is just nonportable. "correct" in programming means "adhering to a specification". Even a program which exhibits undefined behavior can be correct, if it is specified that way. For instance, we can't avoid a division by zero in a program for which the requirement specification says: "develop a program which explores the consequences of an integer division by zero on such and such a machine and operating system".

In this case, the requirement specification, if interpreted earnestly, requires us to have a value which can be directly used as a function pointer and also as a structure pointer if suitably cast, so we can hardly get away from a hack of this sort.

Note that if we are allowed to use preprocessor hacks or other cheats, then these are valid solutions:

```
#if 0
x:  ((struct x *)x)->x = x(5);
#endif
```

The program still "contains the line": the problem doesn't say it has to be a line which is retained after the preprocessing translation phases. Also, comments contain lines too:

```
/*
x:  ((struct x *)x)->x = x(5);
*/
```